# Showing Mathematical Expression in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

for the last few hours I have been racking my brain to try and figure out a way of generating mathematical expressions inside python, and then turning these into images that can be shown in a Kivy application. I have tried multiple libraries and all are either incompatible, outdated or require external programs to achieve this. Is it possible that anyone has an idea about the best way to go around doing this? I would attach some code but not sure if any of it would be very helpful.

Comment: You may use reStructured Text renderer such as [`RstDocument`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.rst.html#module-kivy.uix.rst) for that but I think this has very limited access or syntax for complex mathematical expressions.

Comment: what did you try? We have no idea which modules don't work for you.